# How to recover deleted files from git after switching branch without stash

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-stash

I've made some local changes and didn't pushed to repository, accident tally switched to another branch without stashing my changes, i did

```
git checkout .
```

Now i realized that after switching to my working branch, noticed all my local changes gone. Is there anyway to get it back i mean restore or if i do git checkout ., these files will be moved to any cache or recycle bin, i checked it in recycle bin, but not succeeded.
Any help ?
Thanks in advance

I've checked in my local is there any stash list, but no list. Very disappointing work i did. Is there any way to get back my local changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCode you could have the deleted files in the open editors. Just save the deleted files from the File menu.
Helped to recover all my work recently.

Git offers own recovery tool but I didn't use it yet:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore

I guess it works when you staged your changes.

A 3d pary solution for staged changes: https://github.com/ethomson/git-recover

Maybe some deleted files recovery tools would help like HandyRecovery.

Comment: Hi @alexander-nenashev I'm not using any IDE, its my internal tool, all are play file format.
Anyways thanks for the reply..